# Other deep learning image generation techniques besides GANs?

Tags: deep-learning, reference-request, generative-model, image-generation

Can you please point me to some resources about image genereation besides GANs?
Are there any other techniques throughout history?
How did idea of image generation evolved and how it started?

I tried googling "image generation before gans" and similar alternatives but without any success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several [generative models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generative_model) that have been proposed before or roughly at the same time of the [GAN](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/5423-generative-adversarial-nets.pdf) (2014). For example, the [deep Boltzman machine](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v5/salakhutdinov09a/salakhutdinov09a.pdf) (2009), [deep generative stochastic network](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v32/bengio14.pdf) (2014) or [variational auto-encoder](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.6114.pdf) (2014).